# Is there a search history in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

A feature that I used a lot in Eclipse is the Search History, which remembers searches you performed in the past and gives you quick access to them. I cannot seem to replicate this functionality in IntelliJ - it seems that I have to start a new search each time. Does this feature exist, or does anyone know of a plugin that provides such a feature?

Answer (score 29):

I think what you're looking for is the "Open in new tab" checkbox at the bottom of the "Find in path" dialog. For me by default it was disabled. When you enable it, you will have search results open in separate tabs every time, so accessing historic searches will be much easier.

Answer (score 18):

For recent "Find Usages", open the "Find" window (Cmd 3); click the settings button in the "Find" window toolbar; in the settings dialog check the checkbox "Open in new tab".

Answer (score 12):

Inside 'Find' dock press Alt+Down to see 'Recent Find Usages' dropdown.

Answer (score 12):

Search history intellij alt up or alt down.

[image: search history intellij alt up or alt down]

Answer (score 9):

For in-file search there is **Recent Searches** drop down if you press the down arrow key, the same is available for the `Find in Path` dialog.

Answer (score 4):

Alt+down arrow is what you are looking for...

First press Ctrl+Shift+f and then alt+down arrow

for more info check IntelliJ website:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/searching-everywhere.html#search_all

Answer (score 4):

Using Alt+down works to see previous Finds, but by default only 1 Tab is open.

Of course the setting for opening new Finds in a new Tab can be found in a slightly different place than when the first answer was posted. It can now be found by right-clicking the top bar (or the "Show options menu" gear-icon) -> View Options -> Open Results in New Tab.
[image: Open results in new tab]

Answer (score 2):

Click on the magnifying icon in the find window and you will see it. It is not intutive. I'd expect it to list the previous searches when I click on the text box window.

[image]

Comment: This was the most useful answer for me on IntelliJ 2019.

Answer (score 0):

[image]just when you user find by path, right corner of the search you will find the "open 
 in find window" there you will see history as shown in the image and you can pin the search history you need . just hit the <- arrow button in the left panel of find window, you would see the history